# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden on windows 7 using visual studio 12 for creating a web service

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, windows-7, iis-7.5

Hi i want to create a sample web service i am new to it but when i am running my web service program i am getting the below error..other details are as below --

my AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyFirstWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string simpleMethod(String srt)
        {
            return "Hello " + srt;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int anotherSimpleMethod(int firstNum, int secondNum)
        {
            return firstNum + secondNum;
        }

    }
}
```

When i am running this i am getting

[image]

below is the snapshot of my windows feature's and service --

[image]

My IIS setting are as :

[image]

I ran below command on my cmd 
**%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir**

Please tell me how do i get rid of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the 'default document' (default.aspx, default.asp, index.htm, etc) is not available in your web application. 
Therefore the error as 'directory browsing' is not enabled.
Try to open the webservices's url e.g http://localhost:[port]/webservicename.aspx

hope it helps

Comment: I am getting below error when i am giving http://localhost:50383/simpleMethod.aspx   
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /simpleMethod.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

can you tell me how to put default document?

Answer (score 0):

Side note, make sure you have the right startup project set (long time since I debugged .net :p)